# Processing of the results of the recursive search of subdirectories and files C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, treeview

The task is to implement a recursive enumeration of subdirectories and files for chosen directory.
4 threads:
1st - primary(Application.Run()); 2nd - scans the chosen directory and writes files to some publicly available collection (I do not understand in which one);
3rd - receives from the 2nd thread the information about subdirectory or a file from "publicly availiable collection" and stores the result in xml file (asynchronously). To keep the hierarchy of the directory;
4th - receives from the 2nd thread the information about subdirectory or a file from "publicly availiable collection" and stores the result in treeView (asynchronously). To keep the hierarchy of the directory;
There is a method that performs a recursive search.

```
private void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

        try
        {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
        }           
        // than the application provides. 
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            log.Add(e.Message);
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
//i have introduced variable: count = 0 for understanding, in which 
//direction are we moving through the hierarchy: top or down
                tn[count] = tn[count - 1].Nodes.Add(root.Name.ToString() + " " + count);
                list.Add(new CustomClass(root.Name, count));
            }

            //textBox1.AppendText("Directory: "+root.Name+"\n");
            count++;
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                //textBox1.AppendText(fi.Name +fi.CreationTime+fi.Length+ "\n");
                list.Add(new CustomClass(fi.Name,count));
                tn[count] = tn[count - 1].Nodes.Add(fi.Name +" " + count);
            }
            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
                count--;
            }               
        }
    }
```

i have also the method where i stacked at: method that stores result(subdirectory or file to the xml file)

```
private void WriteToXML()
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Folder","Oreh"));
// root element is created manually, because i can't implement corrctly
// this method even in this way!
        int newcount = 1;
//newcount is a variable with the help of which i can define the direction
//of moving though the hierarchy by comparing with l.ParentID(count in prev. method)
        xElem[newcount] = doc.Root;
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            if (l.ParentID > newcount)
            {
            xElem[newcount +1] = new XElement("Name", l.Name,new Attribute("ID",l.ParentID));
            xElem[newcount].Add(xElem[newcount+ 1]);
            newcount=l.ParentID;
            }
            else if (l.ParentID < newcount)
            {
            newcount --;
            xElem[newcount - 1] = new XElement("Name", l.Name, new XAttribute("ID", l.ParentID));
            xElem[newcount].Add(xElem[newcount - 1]);
            }
            else
            {
            xElem[newcount].Add(new XElement("Name", l.Name, new XAttribute("ID", l.ParentID)));
            }
        }
        doc.Save("Tree.xml");
    }
```

The problem is: i don't know in which collection and how should i store the result, obtained from `WalkDirectoryTree()` method and how to write this result into xml file.

Comment: well. you seem to have a huge mishmash of stuff going on.. list seems to be a global you use in both.. so the obvious answer to write out the xml is once youre done iterating the folders.... count also seems global which also seems an odd way to use it, when you could pass the directory depth and increment as you go down only..  If you didn't use so many globals you could do parallel processing

Comment: i need to implement it with threads only. But firstly, i need to figure out how can i store info about found subdirectory or file to collection(i dont think that i can do it with the help of List<>), and send it both to the method that adds it to xml node(saving hierarchical structure) and to the method that forms treeview. Collection must me public(to be accessed by several threads)

Comment: Your code mangles it all into one list. It doesnt do it per sub directory, so, you have to do it all at the end, or your data wont make sense.

Comment: so how can i do it as subdirectory? How can i make a connection between these nodes? I made it with the help of variable count (i have built treview from that method and it works fine), but it seems to be wrong way. How can i attach each subdirectory and file to its parent directory with the help of collection? Thats almost the main my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a class to simplify things and information. THIS IS AN EXAMPLE. You need to read how to manage null Parents or Zero Directories inside a directory. Consider this some kind of pseudocode

```
class DirInfo
{
public string ParentDir { get; set; };
public string DirName { get; set; };
public string[] files { get; set; };
public DirectoryInfo[] Dirs = null { get; set; };
}

List<DirInfo> Directories = new List<DirInfo>(); 
//We don't really know the amount
//unless we iterate through it, so you can make an array []

private void DirSearch(System.IO.DirectoryInfo Root)
{
//You need to add you own validations when parent is null, or not subdirectories inside or 0 files inside, etc.
Directories.Add(new DirInfo() { ParentDir = Root.Parent.Name, DirName = Root.Name, files = Root.GetFiles("*.*"), Dirs = Root.GetDirectories() };

if(Root.Dirs != null)
for(int i=0; i<Root.Dirs.Lenght; i++){

DirSearch(Root.Dirs[i]);

}

}
```

After this, you will have a list with Directories information like:

```
RootDir { Parent: N/A -> Name: RootDir -> Files: ... File1, FIle2... -> SubDirs: Dir1... Dir2... }

Dir1 { Parent: RootDir -> Name: Dir1 -> Files... ... -> SubDirs: DirSub1, DirSub2... }

DirSub1 { Parent: Dir1 -> Name: DirSub1 -> Files... ... -> SubDirs: Etc, Etc... }
```

Now, you can create an array of dirs, by sorting them... You can select each directory where it's parent is RootDir, Dir1, etc...